# How to identify wso2 request to backend

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to find a relevant source on the internet but i'm unable to find some info on this.

**I want to understand how i can identify wso2 calls to a backend server.**

I can set any custom http headers, but anyone can override that in cURL requests. So that can't be a solution. Any other ideas?

### EDIT

`If its not clear enough` - When i will receive a call in my backend server (the API endpoint) then how would i identify if its coming from wso2 or from somewhere else. May be you will say 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' but that can be overridden automatically.

Comment: can you check the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom mediation sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) (per API) or a [custom handler](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Writing+Custom+Handlers) (global) to inject an http header automatically.

Comment: Like i said adding http header is not a solution because people can invoke API without using wso2 end point (they can use the actual end point) and can inject that custom header in that call. I cant differentiate between those 2 calls.Can i?

Comment: Unless the header value is a secret ;) And is people invoking those endpoints directly a valid case? if yes, why do they want to set the same header in their requests? for a malicious purpose?

Comment: yes..we dont want any anonymous users to access those APIs. There will be admin defined users only. We basically want to restrict other users. And as you know http headers can be overridden easily.

Comment: In that case what you need is an authentication mechanism.

Comment: See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Basic+Auth and https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Digest+Auth

Comment: Any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958320/wso2am-change-store-publisher-carbon-url

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable wire logs for WSO2 API manager. To do this go to
/repository/conf/log4j.properties file and uncomment

```
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

And restart the API Manager.

Outgoing messages from API Manager will be logged with `<<`symbol.

example:

```
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,007] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "GET /am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/menu HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,007] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Origin: https://10.100.5.154:9443[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,007] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Referer: https://10.100.5.154:9443/store/apis/info?name=PizzaShackAPI&version=1.0.0&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: localhost:9443[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2017-08-17 10:10:49,008] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Answer (score 0):

When a request served through WSO2 API Manager or ESB or EI, there are ways that you can log the request and response.

Please enable the wire logs in conf/log4j.properties file as follows.

```
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

There are four logs types that will be printed when you enable that and will be marked by relevant mark.

1. Request comes to server ">>"
2. Request goes out to backend "<<"
3. Response comes to server ">>"
4. Response goes to client "<<"