# WSO2am change store/publisher/carbon url

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed wso2am. After starting the services it gives me 3 urls.

> 1) for store 2) for publisher 3) for carbon

`Now i need to set a domain name rather than IP address in the URLs.` **I am trying to do it on local machine** (Just added the wso2am root folder and running wso2server.bat file).

```
<APIGateway>
                <Environments>
                    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
                        <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
                        <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
                        <ServerURL>https://demodomain.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
                        <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
                        <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
                        <GatewayEndpoint>http://demodomain.com:${http.nio.port},https://demodomain.com:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
                    </Environment>
                </Environments>
        </APIGateway>
```

Here `demodomain.com` is the domain name i am using rather than **localhost or whatever IP wso2 is assigning**.

After this i restart the server and again wso2 provides me URLs with IPs. Its not using `demodomain.com`. If i try to access store/publisher/carbon using that domain name it doesn't load.

Any ideas?

### EDIT

I have gone through https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Customize+the+API+Store+and+Gateway+URLs this. But seems its outdated. I cant find `/_system/governance/customurl/api-cloud/<tenant-id>/urlMapping/<tenant-id>` under `carbon->Browse->Resources`section.

### EDIT

Even after setting this

```
<HostName>demodomain.com</HostName>
```

in `carbon.xml` after restarting i am still seeing the below. Its still generating dynamic IPs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the

`<HostName>demodomain.com</HostName>`

xml tag in `carbon.xml` to `demodomain.com`.

The `<GatewayEndpoint>` tags refer to which endpoints your deployed APIs will be available on.

Comment: Its still generating dynamic ips. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<HostName>demodomain.com</HostName>
<MgtHostName>demodomain.com</MgtHostName>
```

in `carbon.xml`.

Comment: Its still generating dynamic ips. Please check the edit.

Comment: Are you sure you set `MgtHostName`?

Comment: Whats the diff between HostName and MgtHostName tag in `carbon.xml` file?

Comment: Ok. After adding `MgtHostName` its created urls using that domain name. But I have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577121/wso2-api-manager-displaying-correct-ip-in-ui . But do i need to add `10.220.10.126 demodomain.com` in my hosts file too?..But in that case it means its still generating dynamic urls. So time to time i need to update my hosts file too?..How do i know the IP then?

Comment: Is it like i need to put the machine IP like this `<HostName>10.220.10.126</HostName>` and domain name like `<MgtHostName>demodomain.com</MgtHostName>` and then add `10.220.10.126  demodomain.com` in hosts file?

Comment: `MgtHostName` is the hostname of UIs. 
`HostName` is the hostname of services.

Comment: Both of them should have hostnames. Don't you have a static IP for your machine? or are you planning to spin new VMs time to time?